# Liquibase in Grails: “Empty result set, expected one row”

Tags: database, grails, migration, database-migration, liquibase

I made a change to a Grails domain class and ran

`grails db-gorm-diff 2012-11-20-domain-class-change.groovy --add` (obviously with another name there)

and was getting a “change lock” error from Liquibase:

`Error executing bootstraps: liquibase.exception.LockException: Could not acquire change log lock. Currently locked by computer-name.local […]`

So (stupidly, it seems) following the advice in [an aged thread dealing with a similar problem with the Autobase plugin](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-migrate-with-Autobase-tp2231222p2231522.html), I deleted the rows in the change log lock table:

`mysql> delete from DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK;`

and now get this beautiful Liquibase error:

`Error executing bootstraps: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Empty result set, expected one row`

which clearly tells me, too late to change this, that I shouldn’t have deleted that row from the table.

What can I do about this now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a script for this in the plugin - use http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/ref/Maintenance%20Scripts/dbm-release-locks.html

Answer (score 3):

I dug around some more in general Liquibase-related places and now learn that I can simply [drop the table altogether](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/message-regarding-an-empty-result-set-for-databasechangeloglock) and have it recreated on startup. This seems to have worked.

Answer (score 2):

Look at http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/message-regarding-an-empty-result-set-for-databasechangeloglock . You just need to set 'locked' row to 1 or to drop databasechangelock table entirely (it will be recreated then)